# Buying multiple SKProducts with single payment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm walking through In App guide and trying to figure out how to deal with buying multiple products. Let's say I have 3 features available to buy via IAP and I want to have option to select which ones user is willing to buy, then buy all selected at once. Should I create only 3 products (for each feature) or should I create one product for each possible combination of available features (like: A, B, C, A+B, A+C, A+B+C...) ? I tried to google it, but I have nothing so far, not sure if I'm asking good question or what. Can anyone direct me somewhere, some tutorial or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The In App Purchase SDK present only the `paymentWithProduct:` method which enable only one product as parameter. You may only set the quantity to be more than 1.
If you want to propose package of In-App you should register them as separate In-App on itunesConnect and propose them in your app. But if you don't set a price different than the sum of the separate products, I don't see a real advantage to the user.

Comment: only advantage would be not tapping several times for purchase, but for one with accumulated price... so I guess that all I can do is create products that are combinations of available features, right?